# Безопасность применения делегатов

Tags: делегаты, c#

Добрый вечер! Вопрос чисто теоретический- в чём заключается безопасность применения делегатов?

Answer (score 7):

Безопасность делегатов связана с их строгой типизированностью. С одной стороны делегат можно упрощенно представить как указатель на некую функцию. Но с другой стороны делегат в  отличие от обычного указателя кроме адреса функции хранит еще и информацию о количестве параметров, их типах и порядке следования, а также о возвращаемом значении. А потому делегату нельзя "подсунуть" какой-то метод, чья сигнатура не соответствует той, что представляет делегат. Иными словами, если  у вас есть делегат такого вида:

```
delegate int MyDelegate(string str)
```

то вы не сможете написать вот так:

```
MyDelegate del = (int a) => a
```

То есть делегат определенного типа требует и определенную сигнатуру. А это значит, что вы избавляетесь от потенциальных проблем, при  которых (будь вместо делегатов просто указатели на какие-то функции) получали бы исключения в рантайме. А так будете получать ошибки компиляции, что куда менее критично.